# What is this brick with a round back and a stud on the side used for?

Tags: piece-information

I haven't seen this part before. What is it? What is it used for?

[image: Part photo]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This part is [3386 Plate 1 x 1 x 2/3 Half Round with Side Stud](https://rebrickable.com/parts/3386/plate-1-x-1-x-23-half-round-with-side-stud/).

[image: 3386 part render]

I recently encountered this part for the first time and wanted to share more about it as it is new to me and looks very useful. It was launched in 2023 and appeared originally in 3 speed champions sets:

[image: Speed Champions sets including this part]

In terms of the height and side stud placement, it is similar to [87609](https://rebrickable.com/parts/87609/plate-special-2-x-6-x-23-with-4-studs-on-side-1-support-wall-on-bottom/71/) and [99206](https://rebrickable.com/parts/99206/plate-special-2-x-2-x-0667-with-two-studs-on-side-and-two-raised/)

[image: 87609]

[image: 99206]

It's even a bit like the classic [Erling brick](https://rebrickable.com/parts/4070a/brick-special-1-x-1-with-headlight-and-slot/7/) when the brick is used on it's side:

[image: 4070]

This is one of the smallest brick-like parts available that provides two studs at 90 degree angles from one another. It fills a role somewhat similar to the smallest brackets, [36840](https://rebrickable.com/parts/36840/bracket-1-x-1-1-x-1-inverted/71/) and [36841](https://rebrickable.com/parts/36841/bracket-1-x-1-1-x-1/71/):

[image: 36840]

[image: 36841]

This part shares its footprint with [24246 Tile Round 1 x 1 Half Circle](https://rebrickable.com/parts/24246/tile-round-1-x-1-half-circle/72/):

[image: Tile 1x1 half circle]

It does have some unique advantages. It's very easy to sneak this part in where it would otherwise be difficult to create a studs out connection. Here are some examples from the first wave of sets:

[image: 76916 step 53]

[image: 76916 step 65]

[image: 76915 step 27]

[image: 76915 step 28]

Another advantage of these parts is that they can be used to recreate the 5 plate tall bricks with studs on side in a way that should be usable in most contexts where these elements are needed:

[image: 1x1 snot bricks]

The geometry of these parts also makes them useful for microscale building. Here's a quick example of a train car that uses these elements to attach the wheels:

[image: Train wheel attachment]

The rounded back of the part also allows it to be used at varying angles as demonstrated in this [quick X-wing design](https://rebrickable.com/mocs/MOC-146985/jncraton/x-wing/):

[image: X-wing step 1]

[image: X-wing step 2]

[image: X-wing step 3]

[image: X-wing]

This looks like a part that could open up a number of new building opportunities.

Here's a final clever example of this part being used upside down to create a tiny toilet on the [Concorde](https://brickset.com/article/98631/review-10318-concorde):

[image: Concorde Toilet]